# How to change empty() filter?

Tags: php, wordpress

I got some posts sorted by their `$referrals` value, which always is a number. As soon, as a post does not include the value, or the value is `0`, the post will not be displayed.

I want to change this and display the post containing the value `0`. I guess its being filtered here:

```
$referrals = ( empty( $referrals ) ) ? 0 : $referrals;
```

How can I change this? Reading about `empty` I have learned that it checks if there is empty, not defined or null, and if thats the case it returns `true`. So I guess I cannot use `empty` anymore?

Comment: I don't think that's the relevant code. This line doesn't make any changes to anything other than itself, so it won't be filtering any posts in the thing you sorted.

Comment: Add `&& $referrals != 0` to the ternary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your value in function, and if less than 1 or not a number then return 0. The default 0 in the method for the referrals argument will ensure it doesn't fail if the value is empty.

```
function setReferrals($referrals = 0) {

    return ($referrals < 1 || is_nan($referrals)) ? 0 : $referrals;

}

 echo setReferrals(0) . "<br>";
 echo setReferrals() . "<br>";
 echo setReferrals(null) . "<br>";
 echo setReferrals(1) . "<br>";
 echo setReferrals(200) . "<br>";
 echo setReferrals('ABC') . "<br>";

// output: 
// 0
// 0
// 0
// 1
// 200
// 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  try this:

```
$referrals = ( empty( $referrals ) &&  $referrals != 0) ? 0 : $referrals;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `is_null` or `isset`:

```
$referrals = ( (isset( $referrals )) and (is_null($referrals ))) ? 0 : $referrals;
```